# c# webclient async

Tags: c#, asynchronous, webclient

I have inherited a c# application that samples data from ~380 sites via Webclient downloadfileasync.  A separate thread is created for each site! (the downloads each wait a timeout period before downloading the next data - so load is not constant....but still!)  Anyway, As the number of sites will increase (likely dramatically) over the next year or so, I would like to change this to a few (reasonable number) of worker threads that issue a bunch of Webclient downloadfileasync calls for a subset of the sites.  But I am not sure what might happen if multiple downloads complete concurrently - will the downloadfilecompleted event handler be serialized by webclient?  Or can multiple webclient completions occur "simultaneously" (or more likely, interleaved)? Will I be running the risk of one completion corrupting another?  Or does anyone have a better suggestion on how to manage the explosion of threads in the current implementation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of the framework are you using?

Comment: If you are using DownloadFileAsync it already is in its own thread.  So the use of yet another thread is sort of pointless and not very effective.

Comment: Like Jon Skeet says, a feature of asynchronous tasks is preventing thread blocking. You probably should do a baseline profile of your application in Performance Monitor using some of [these counters](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc768048.aspx) to be able to compare what adding more sites to your application process will do. It'll also give you a good place to start if you need to do any optimization.

Answer (score 2):

I would *expect* multiple completion events to potentially be raised concurrently - but unless *you* have some shared state that you don't handle carefully, it should be fine. The results shouldn't get "corrupted" - if they do, that's definitely a bug in .NET.

Note that if you're using async calls, you probably don't need the worker threads - the whole point of doing things async is that you issue the call and then *don't* block a thread, so it's fine to do that from the UI thread (or whatever).

If you're able to use bleeding-edge technology, the async/await feature in C# 5 / .NET 4.5 (which is in Release Candidate mode) could make your life a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks to all 4 responders.  My only reason to consider working treads was to possible "harness" multiple cpus as the load grows. And I wasn't sure if the "completion" routine executed under the thread of the async get, or "my" thread (if under async get thread, then I might need locks??)

Comment: By default I believe `WebClient` will rendezvous back with the synchronization context that starts it - but unless you're doing a *lot* of work with the response, I wouldn't expect that to be an issue.